# WKWebView File System Browser

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I've been asked to add a file browser to an existing `Objective C` application that uses a `WKWebView` to load up a `Javascript` internal app.

Currently we have the capability of looking at the pictures on device to upload images into the app, but I've now been asked to do the same with more generic file types, specifically `PDFs`.

What I've read so far is that this is only possible if a file is stored in a specific part of the file system and only if the app knows exactly where the file is to begin with, but what I need is the capability to browse to a certain degree.

What I'd like to know is whether this is possible and if there is a good place to start on that?

Thanks.

Comment: You can only access files of other types (like pdf) only if they are in the cloud or if you want to access the local files (files on device), you can only access the files within the sandbox of your app. Read more about sandbox [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html)

Comment: Also read about the document picker [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)